# Remove a specific value from array in each loop - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to be able to remove values from an array which contain the value `round`.

An example array submitted could be `[team1, team2, round3, round5, team3, round6]`

I have this code which is meant to loop through the array and remove an element from the array if it contains `round` using `search`

```
function modifyFilterConfig(idStr, target) {
$.each(idStr, function(i, value){
    console.log("The index of this value is: " + i);
    console.log("The value is: " + value);
    console.log("The value match is: " + value.search(target));
    if(value.search(target) == 0) {
        // IF THE ARRAY CONTAINS A ROUND REMOVED IT FROM THE ARRAY
        // i - 1 is the current index of the array (i.e. the ROUND filter(s))
        idStr = idStr.splice(i - 1, 1);
    }
    i = i++;
});
console.log("Return value:");
console.log(idStr);
return idStr;
}
```

At the moment the results I get are the last team in the array for example `team6` but my desired result is `[team2, team3, team6]`

Finally, I want the function to return an array as well so I use it the array again in my wider code.

`console.log("IDS before processing: " + ids);
 var ids = modifyFilterConfig(ids, "round");
 console.log("IDS after processing: " + ids);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `filter` function and use the RegExp `test` method.

```js
var arr = ["team1", "team2", "round3", "round5", "team3", "round6"]
arr = arr.filter(e => !/round/.test(e));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Smashed it Richard! What is browser compatibility like for such a function?

Comment: It should be functional in most browsers if I remember correctly